# What is the interaction between _Layout.cshtml and my ViewFile.cshtml?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

In the _Layout.cshtml there are references to jQuery, and bootstrap.min.js.
Yet in my ViewFile page, I cannot get DataTables to work unless I include the reference to jQuery, and data tables.  This is in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac.  I'm trying to get a paged table, that responds to browser resize, has column sorting, search function, nice looking buttons for first, next, etc. with the  page size selector on the upper left and the search window on the upper right.  I keep getting different combinations, and when it looks right, there are no column sort buttons, etc.  Here is what is in the _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Maestro</title>
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="LogFileViewer" asp-action="SelectFile" class="navbar-brand">Maestro</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="LogFileViewer" asp-action="SelectFile">LogFiles</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2018 - Maestro</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And at the top of my ViewFile.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "View";
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
}
```

table is defined as:

```
  <table id="table_id" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
```

and below the table is:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function ()
    {
    $('#table_id').dataTable( {
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "scrollY"  : "400px",
                "paging": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "searching": true,
                "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                "serverSide": false, // for process server side
                "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
                "columnDefs":
                [{
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                }],
                 "columns": [
                    { "data": "DateTime", "name": "DateTime", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Msecs", "name": "Msecs", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Thread", "name": "Thread", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Level", "name": "Level", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Logger", "name": "Logger", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Host", "name": "Host", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "MsgType", "name": "MsgType", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Message", "name": "Message", "autoWidth": true }
                ]

            });
        });</script>

> Is there some interaction between the js and css files in the
> _Layout.cshtml and the ones at the top of the ViewFile.cshtml?
> 
> What would be THE set of js and css files to include to get what I
> want?  I can't find images of what a set does.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your datatable javascript code in @section scripts {} in ViewFile.cshtml

```
@section scripts {
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
}
```

And place your other javascript code (for datatable initialization) inside the section

Comment: Thanks!  This really helped.  The column sort buttons appeared when I followed your advice.  I'm not sure what the scripts in _Layout.cshtml actually do, but the above fixed my problem.

Comment: While rendering the **ViewFile.cshtml** with **_Layout.cshtml**, your javascript will appear before the jquery script.. (after `@RenderBody()` you are declaring jquery and other javascript files). For this reason it doesn't work. To resolve this we have sections, what ever you declare/write javascript code inside the section it will come in the place of `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)`